# Assign a literal to an std::u16string or to an std::u32string

Tags: c++, c++11

As I know I may assign to a string a literal value as:

```
std::string s="good";
std::wstring s=L"good";
```

how do I assign to a

```
std::u16string s= 
std::u32string s=
```

Comment: And what do you intend `x?x"good"` to mean?

Comment: I want just to assign a string value

Comment: typedef basic_string<char16_t> u16string; as described in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/u16string/

Answer (score 25):

You can read about the C++ string literals [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

In particular for UTF-16 literals you prefix with a lowercase u:

```
u16string s = u"...";
```

And for UTF-32 literals you prefix with a uppercase U:

```
u32string s = U"...";
```